# Java if statement with logical && operator giving errors

Tags: java, function, if-statement

I have to write a program which is based on the speeding penalties of UK. So if a driver could be disqualified from driving if s/he builds up 12 or more penalty points within a period of 3 years and if s/he is still within 2 years of passing his/her driving test, his/her driving licence will be revoked (withdrawn) if he/she builds up 6 or more penalty points.

Here is my program:

```
package lesson1;
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);


  speeding_penalties(13,2);


}

public static void speeding_penalties(int points, int years){


    if((points=>12)&& (years<=3)){
        System.out.println("disqualified");

    }

    else if((points=>6)&& (years<=2)){
        System.out.println("revoked driving license");
     }


  }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting an error at  the `if` statements which gives me the following error:

`The operator && is undefined for arguments type(s) int, boolean'

edit: 
Thank you all for the answers! I have edited the program by changing the operator to >= but still when I am compiling the program, the print statements are not appearing.

Comment: `=>` is not an operator in Java, use `>=` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used a nonexsistant operator.

Here is a summary of the java operators:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

The important ones here being:
`>=`      Greater than or equal to
`<=`      Less than or equal to

`=>` as you used doesn't exist.

Comment: Someone literally doing it for all answers. :). Upvote from my end.

Answer (score 3):

You have a mistake at your operator.
It's `'>='` and `'<='` (you used `'=>'`).

Comment: I have corrected my mistake but still when I am calling the function, the print statements are not appearing upon compilation of the program.

Comment: @Diksha, i copied your code, fixed the two `=>` mistakes, saved it as MyClass.java, `javac MyClass.java`, `java MyClass` and it printed `disqualified`. Wait, upon compilation of the program? You also have to run it.

Comment: @Froziph I did run it but it's not printing `disqualified`

Comment: @Froziph I restarted my pc and it's working now.. Thank you! I guess the problem was in the compiler

Comment: @Diksha, Great! :-) BTW, you can consider accepting an answer that helped you, which also makes it clear the problem is solved. Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

```
points=>12
```

If you look carefully, you need to write `points>=12`

`=>` getting treated as assignment operator where `>=` is relational operator which checks against the given value.

`points=>12`  `-->` Silently assigned the value to `points` and return `points`.

`points>=12`  `-->` Checks the value of  `points` >= 12 and return a `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error:

```
points=>12
```

It should be:

```
points>=12
```